# Have IntelliJ warn me before committing to master

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is it possible to have IntelliJ IDEA warn me before committing to the `master` branch? I find myself frequently committing changes to `master` that I should really be putting on a feature-branch, and sometimes I notice this only after a few commits. It is not difficult to undo this mistake and move the commits to a new branch, but I'd prefer not having to do it, in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

The great thing in git, as you noted, is the fact that you could easily revert/move wrong commits to the correct branch.
Adding warnings or confirmation doesn't seem like a good idea because they tend to be ignored by habit in time and become just an unnecessary step.

Probably what you need here is a more clear indication which branch the commit will go to. Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63893.

Comment: Thanks, although I do think that a warning would be a nice addition (would not have to be turned on by default, but could be an option in the settings). In any case, I've voted for that issue, I'd be happy to see this in an upcoming release :)